# arcgis runtime libraries not being picked up when running standalone jar?

Tags: java, arcgis-runtime

Hello everyone i am struggling with an issue with arcgis sdk for java. i have obtained the sdk and jars by following the maven guide mentioned in the docs https://developers.arcgis.com/java/latest/guide/get-the-sdk.htm and after that i ran the dependency:unpack goal and i can see the runtime files at the `homedirectory/.arcgis` directory and when i run the project from the eclipse ide it works just fine, but as soon as i convert the jar into an executable jar and try to run it it gives me the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find runtime in any of:
- A directory specified by calling ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.setInstallDirectory()
- The current directory E:\eclipseprojects\gisdemo
- A location specified by the environment variable ARCGISRUNTIMESDKJAVA_100_7_0
- Within the ".arcgis" directory in the user's home path C:\Users\wickwayne\.arcgis
```

the executable jar starts working once i place the jnilibs and resources from .arcgis\100.7.0 directory right next to my jar's project file, but why is this so ,why isn't arcgis run-time being picked up from the users home directory when it is already there? Need help

Comment: My guess is that jnilibs and resources from .arcgis/100.7.0/ must be located in .arcgis/ (without version directory)

Comment: @YuryNevinitsin maybe you should post this as an answer so i can accept it,cant believe how dumb i have been to overlook such an issue,still learning new things everyday:-)

Comment: @YuryNevinitsin dont forget to upvote the question though:-)

Comment: This question (imho, of course), does not add much knowledge for all of us. It is more like finding a typo with a fresh eye. I will not upvote it thus. But what will make world better is the following. The maven part of the doc says "Run the Maven dependency:unpack goal. This will unpack the native libraries into $USER_HOME/.arcgis", but actually there was additional version subdirectory. Thats why you could not run it out-of-the-box. So I suggest you report this issue to arcgis developers and they fix it.

Comment: Too bad this isn't actually the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to add at the beginning of your code:

```
ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.setInstallDirectory("path\\arcgis-runtime-sdk-java-100.7.0");
```